# forループ中での3次元配列への数字の挿入と条件分岐について

Tags: python

forループ中での3次元配列への数字の挿入と条件分岐で困っています。

li1[i][j][k]の数字とli2[l][1]が一致した際に、li2[l][0]とli2[l][2]を、li1の中のli2[l][1]の前後に挿入したいと考えています。

```
li1=[[[0, 1, 10], [0, 2, 10]], 
 [[0, 1, 3, 5, 10], [0, 1, 3, 6, 10], [0, 1, 4, 5, 10], [0, 1, 4, 6, 10], [0, 2, 3, 5, 10], [0, 2, 3, 6, 10], [0, 2, 4, 5, 10], [0, 2, 4, 6, 10]]]

li2=[[7,1,8], [9,2,11], [12,3,13], [14,4,15], [16,5,17], [18,6,19]]

for i in range(len(li1)):
    for j in range(len(li1[i])):
        for k in range(1,len(li1[i][j])-1):
            for l in range(len(li2)):#
                if li1[i][j][k]==li2[l][1]:
                    li1[i][j].insert(k,li2[l][0])
                    li1[i][j].insert(k+2,li2[l][2])


print(li1)


>>> 
[[[0, 7, 1, 8, 10], [0, 9, 2, 11, 10]], 
 [[0, 7, 7, 7, 1, 8, 8, 8, 3, 5, 10], [0, 7, 7, 7, 1, 8, 8, 8, 3, 6, 10], [0, 7, 7, 7, 1, 8, 8, 8, 4, 5, 10], [0, 7, 7, 7, 1, 8, 8, 8, 4, 6, 10], [0, 9, 9, 9, 2, 11, 11, 11, 3, 5, 10], [0, 9, 9, 9, 2, 11, 11, 11, 3, 6, 10], [0, 9, 9, 9, 2, 11, 11, 11, 4, 5, 10], [0, 9, 9, 9, 2, 11, 11, 11, 4, 6, 10]]]
```

最終的な結果として3次元配列のresultを導出したいと考えています。
上の結果ですと7や8などが3回連続してしまっていたり、下のresultと全く異なった結果となってしまっている状況です。

```
result=[[[0,7,1,8,10],[0,9,2,11,10]],
    [[0,7,1,8,12,3,13,18,6,19,10],[0,7,1,8,12,3,13,18,6,19,10],[0,7,1,8,14,4,15,16,5,17,10], [0,7,1,8,14,4,15,18,6,19,10], [0, 2, 3, 5,10], [0,9,2,11,12,3,13,18,6,19,10], [0,9,2,11,14,4,15,16,5,17,10], [0,9,2,11,14,4,15,18,6,19,10]]]
```

別の書き方でも全く問題ないです。よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 回答をもらったら、どれか「採用」しましょう。回答者にポイントが入って評価が上がり、また回答するモチベーションになったり、回答者の信憑性判断の基準になったりします。この質問だけでなく、他の質問でも回答がたくさん付いていると思うので、「採用」してあげてください。

Answer (score 2):

`insert()` によって `li1[i][j]` の長さが変化してしまいますので、`k` をインデックスとして使うとおかしな事になってしまいます。別の変数(`m`)をインデックスとして使う様に変更します。

```
for i in range(len(li1)):
  for j in range(len(li1[i])):
    m = 0
    for k in range(1,len(li1[i][j])-1):
      m += 1 
      for l in range(len(li2)):
        if li1[i][j][m]==li2[l][1]:
          li1[i][j].insert(m,li2[l][0])
          li1[i][j].insert(m+2,li2[l][2])
          m += 2
```

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。参考にさせていただきます。

Answer (score 2):

ループの途中でループ対象のリストをいじれば、インデックスが変わりますから、どんどん面倒になります。
リストを組み立てる場合は、既存のリストを変更するのでは無く、新しいリストを作ると楽です。

まずは`li1`を新しいリストにコピーするコードを考えてみて下さい。
そして、`li1`の要素を足していく箇所に、条件により処理を加える、という流れです。

以下は質問のコードを出来るだけそのままで、新規リストを作る方法に変更した物です。
処理を加える部分を別の関数に切り出すですとか、いろいろと整理する方法は考えられますが。

出力は質問で示されている`result`とは一致しないですね。
どちらかに間違いがあるのでしょう。

```python
#!/usr/bin/python3

li1=[[[0, 1, 10], [0, 2, 10]], 
 [[0, 1, 3, 5, 10], [0, 1, 3, 6, 10], [0, 1, 4, 5, 10], [0, 1, 4, 6, 10], [0, 2, 3, 5, 10], [0, 2, 3, 6, 10], [0, 2, 4, 5, 10], [0, 2, 4, 6, 10]]]

li2=[[7,1,8], [9,2,11], [12,3,13], [14,4,15], [16,5,17], [18,6,19]]

result = []

for i in range(len(li1)):
    result.append([])
    for j in range(len(li1[i])):
        result[-1].append([])
        for k in range(len(li1[i][j])):
            if k == 0 or k == len(li1[i][j]) - 1:
                result[-1][-1].append(li1[i][j][k])
            else:
                add = [ li1[i][j][k] ] 
                for l in range(len(li2)):
                    if li1[i][j][k] == li2[l][1]:
                        add = li2[l]
                        break
                result[-1][-1].extend(add)


from pprint import pprint
pprint(result)
```

結果

```python
[[[0, 7, 1, 8, 10], [0, 9, 2, 11, 10]],
 [[0, 7, 1, 8, 12, 3, 13, 16, 5, 17, 10],
  [0, 7, 1, 8, 12, 3, 13, 18, 6, 19, 10],
  [0, 7, 1, 8, 14, 4, 15, 16, 5, 17, 10],
  [0, 7, 1, 8, 14, 4, 15, 18, 6, 19, 10],
  [0, 9, 2, 11, 12, 3, 13, 16, 5, 17, 10],
  [0, 9, 2, 11, 12, 3, 13, 18, 6, 19, 10],
  [0, 9, 2, 11, 14, 4, 15, 16, 5, 17, 10],
  [0, 9, 2, 11, 14, 4, 15, 18, 6, 19, 10]]]
```

Comment: resultは私の入力が間違っておりました。ご迷惑をお掛けしました。
回答ありがとうございます。大変参考になりました。